# jboss deployment issue - can not visit servlet

Tags: servlets, jboss, web-deployment

I am trying to write a simple web application and deploy on jboss EAP 6. The application is named "webapp" and I was able to build and deploy it to jboss. The context root is /webapp.

I was able to then visit localhost:8080/webapp and it returns a "Hello World" printed from the defaulted index.jsp that was generated by eclipse at /src/main/webapp.

However, when I tried to actually visit the servlet at localhost:8080/webapp/sessionsetup I got the following error:

```
JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 404 - /webapp/sessionsetup

JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report

JBWEB000068: message /webapp/sessionsetup

JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000124: The requested resource is not available.
```

Below is my simple code for the servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/sessionsetup")
public class SessionSetup extends HttpServlet{

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SessionSetup.class);

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    log.info(this.toString());
    log.info("Do get method is called");

    response.setContentType("text/xml");

    PrintWriter printer = response.getWriter();
    printer.println("<html>");
    printer.println("<head>" + "</head>");
    printer.println("<body>");
    printer.println("<h1>" + "Welcome! You are in session setup" + "</h1>");
    printer.println("</body>");
    printer.println("</html>");

    printer.close();
    }

}
```

Could anyone comment on where I might miss something? Is there a way to find some log information no this error? I tried to look for server.log at /standalone/log but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3):

There can be 2 reasons
(1) you can configure your standalone.xml in jboss server
virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">

use false instead of true in enable-welcome-root

(2)
you have not done mapping of controller properly

Comment: Thank you. my problem enable-welcome-root="true". I modified it.

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved. It appears to be an issue with the web.xml - once this is removed, the servlet is available.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem should be the way how it was deployed(Run time name) in the jboss.

So if you try to access  the application on that it  should works.

Runtime Name:   Name by which the deployment should be known within a server's runtime. This would be equivalent to the file name of a deployment file, and would form the basis for such things as default Java Enterprise Edition application and module names. This would typically be the same as 'name', but in some cases users may wish to have two deployments with the same 'runtime-name' (e.g. two versions of "foo.war") both available in the deployment content repository, in which case the deployments would need to have distinct 'name' values but would have the same 'runtime-name'.

Answer (score 0):

This is just my experience about how this problem might happen and the way I have solved issue.

This problems happens in the absence of war file. When I deployed

> hawtio

to monitoring jboss which it needs

> jolokia

so I just download and deployed manually the .war file into my jboss then problem has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml file in which you have set the context root

```
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>contextroot</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Clean Server** to solve this problem in many cases work..